# Custom, dynamic error page with Spring framework

Tags: spring, exception, error-handling, custom-error-pages

I would like my App to display a custom error page when an Exception is thrown. The response containing the page should have the right HTTP status and contain the exception message and possibly other data from the exception object.

I have already tried 2 approaches and neither of them works:

1) Returning a ModelAndView from a `AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver` subclass - I can generate whatever error page i want but it gets served with a 200 OK HTTP status.

2) Specifying an error page in web.xml - I can't find a way to access the exception.

Ok, solved it. Turned out to be pretty easy actually. I used `HttpServletResponse.setStatus`. Note that using `sendError` doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

you could configure the `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`

```
<bean id="exceptionResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
        <property name="defaultStatusCode" value="500" />
        <property name="defaultErrorView" value="error/500" />
        <property name="exceptionMappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error/500</prop>
                <prop key="SomeOtherException">error/custom</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="statusCodes">
            <props>
                <prop key="error/500">500</prop>
                <prop key="error/custom">404</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

and configure your 404 error page in web.xml (spring dispatcher servlet returns status code 404 if no mapping was found)

in your jsp you can access the exception throws as follows

```
${exception}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

- use [the `@ExceptionHandler` mechanism](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) or
- [customize the Default Servlet Container Error Page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-customer-servlet-container-error-page)

Comment: @ ExceptionHandler works only on a per-Controller basis and the error page thing doesn't let me mess around with the Exception